# Minimum requirements for jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-applications, mobile

I am in the early stages of building a mobile web application for the [CN50](http://www.intermec.co.uk/products/cmptrcn50/index.aspx) using the  [Intermec HTML 5 browser](http://www.intermec.co.uk/products/html5/index.aspx). I would like to use jQuery Mobile but I am a little worried as the device only has 128MB of RAM.

Right now I am just using basic HTML, CSS & JS . Do you recommend I use jQuery Mobile instead?

Thanks

Comment: Why not grab a device and then point it at some jQuery Mobile sites that already exist?

Answer (score 2):

I would say then if it's a Web Kit Based HTML 5 supported browser then to use JQuery mobile. The easiest way to check is to get the demo site and just view that in your device and see how well it fares during testing.

This is the table of supported systems/devices from JQuery Mobile 1.2

**A-grade – Full enhanced experience with Ajax-based animated page transitions.**

```
Apple iOS 3.2*-6.0 - Tested on the original iPad (4.3 / 5.0), iPad 2 (4.3), iPad 3 (5.1 / 6.0), original iPhone (3.1), iPhone 3 (3.2), 3GS (4.3), 4 (4.3 / 5.0), and 4S (5.1 / 6.0)
Android 2.1-2.3 – Tested on the HTC Incredible (2.2), original Droid (2.2), HTC Aria (2.1), Google Nexus S (2.3). Functional on 1.5 & 1.6 but performance may be sluggish, tested on Google G1 (1.5)
Android 3.2 (Honeycomb)  – Tested on the Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 and Motorola XOOM
Android 4.0 (ICS)  – Tested on a Galaxy Nexus. Note: transition performance can be poor on upgraded devices
Android 4.1 (Jelly Bean)  – Tested on a Galaxy Nexus and Galaxy 7
Windows Phone 7-7.5 – Tested on the HTC Surround (7.0) HTC Trophy (7.5), LG-E900 (7.5), Nokia Lumia 800
Blackberry 6.0 – Tested on the Torch 9800 and Style 9670
Blackberry 7 – Tested on BlackBerry® Torch 9810
Blackberry Playbook (1.0-2.0) – Tested on PlayBook
Palm WebOS (1.4-2.0) – Tested on the Palm Pixi (1.4), Pre (1.4), Pre 2 (2.0)
Palm WebOS 3.0 – Tested on HP TouchPad
Firefox Mobile 15 – Tested on Android 2.3 and 4.1 devices
Chrome for Android 18 – Tested on Android 4.0 and 4.1 devices
Skyfire 4.1 - Tested on Android 2.3 device
Opera Mobile 11.5-12: Tested on Android 2.3
Meego 1.2 – Tested on Nokia 950 and N9
Tizen (pre-release) – Tested on early hardware
Samsung Bada 2.0 – Tested on a Samsung Wave 3, Dolphin browser
UC Browser – Tested on Android 2.3 device
Kindle 3 and Fire - Tested on the built-in WebKit browser for each
Nook Color 1.4.1 – Tested on original Nook Color, not Nook Tablet
Chrome Desktop 11-21 - Tested on OS X 10.7 and Windows 7
Safari Desktop 4-5 - Tested on OS X 10.7 and Windows 7
Firefox Desktop 4-15 – Tested on OS X 10.7 and Windows 7
Internet Explorer 7-10 – Tested on Windows XP, Vista and 7
Opera Desktop 10-12 - Tested on OS X 10.7 and Windows 7
```

**B-grade – Enhanced experience except without Ajax navigation features.**

```
Blackberry 5.0*: Tested on the Storm 2 9550, Bold 9770
Opera Mini 7 - Tested on iOS 5.1 and Android 2.3
Nokia Symbian^3 - Tested on Nokia N8 (Symbian^3), C7 (Symbian^3), also works on N97 (Symbian^1)
```

**C-grade – Basic, non-enhanced HTML experience that is still functional**

```
Blackberry 4.x - Tested on the Curve 8330
Windows Mobile - Tested on the HTC Leo (WinMo 5.2)
All older smartphone platforms and featurephones – Any device that doesn’t support media queries will receive the basic, C grade experience
```

Comment: The thing has a WebKit-based browser, according to the manufacturer.

Comment: Edited answer to account for that. TL;DR: Go for it, use jquery mobile.